# How to ensure when a html file is printed pdf, at some points new pages must start?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, brave

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74871408/how-to-print-multiple-html-files-into-a-single-pdf-file

The current question stems from the above question.

If I merge multiple HTML files into a single HTML file, I want to make sure when I print the single file to PDF, the original HTML pages all started with a new PDF page. How can I achieve this? Is there an HTML tag that a browser might understand when printing an HTML file to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with CSS by specifying a print media rule that applies the page-break-before or page-break-after to a specific element inserted in HTML as a divider between each original html page. Alternatively if you have some container element to each original HTML, you could apply the rule to that.

Something like:

```
@media print {
    .divider {
        page-break-after: always;
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the corresponding HTML code to be used with this CSS?